# When reading files in Python (on mac) the printed out text is incorrect

Tags: python

I am trying out a simple command, to open and read a file. I have created a text edit file and saved it as test.txt (This file has irrelevant text on it). When I run my program there are no errors and the print commands are executed, except that the wrong information is printed.This is my code:

```
f = open("test2.docx","r")
line1 = f.readline()
line2 = f.readline()
line3 = f.readline()
print line1, line2, line3
```

This is what is written in the text file:

```
COF180;10;40
COF181;10;90
PHF110;15;73
PHF210;15;81
```

This is what is printed out by the program:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1344\cocoasubrtf720
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
```

This seems to be some sort of hidden code about the text itself? Please help I have no idea why this is happening. How do I make it print the actual text from that file?

Comment: Can you produce the code you're using to read the file? What's the input, what's the output that's "wrong" - why is it not what you expected... etc...

Comment: What have you done to read the file?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question, I accidentally clicked post before I had finished asking it...

Comment: When you say "text file", do you actually mean a ".txt" file, or do you mean something like ".doc" or ".rtf" etc? Because that looks a whole lot like format specifiers for some form of rich text.

Comment: Im not sure, I am using a mac, so initially I just used text edit which produces a .rtf file, that did not work, so I simply changed it to .txt, that did not work either, then i tried to use word (.docx), which also did not work...
How do I produce a simple text file on mac?

Comment: ^ This is the actual question. You are not working with a genuine plain text file. Changing the file extension does not convert the file type.

Comment: If you are using TextEdit, from the menu bar select `Format` -> `Make Plain Text`.

Comment: Thank you @NedDeily It works now. Why do people down vote a question like this?

Comment: @JackHayton Those were likely from before you edited the question, when you hadn't presented enough information.

Comment: I agree with @aruisdante - your question spent ~10 minutes with absolutely no info. or anyway for people to help you. Now it's been edited, and there's an obvious problem, maybe the downvoters will undo their votes...

Comment: Just my opinion (and that's all DVs are, opinions) but leaving mine in place because of the "not useful" criterion. It would be very difficult for someone with this problem to come to the solution as this stands because it is buried in comments, the title and presentation of the question distract from it, and there is no answer, accepted or otherwise. This question is kind of a mess.

Comment: Also, if you're going to be doing software development, you'll need to use a suitable text editor.  There are plenty of them out there and there are endless debates over each one's merits. But `TextEdit` is not one of them.  It was never designed for that.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses, now that this is resolved how do I accept @NedDeily's answer and resolve this question? Im still new to stack overflow.

Comment: There's an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using TextEdit, from the menu bar select Format -> Make Plain Text.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac, and you have to do this for multiple files, use the `textutil` utility:

`textutil -convert txt /path/to/files/*.rtf`

This also works for files with .doc extensions.